# Node.js isomorphic-react-example error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, handlebars.js

I saw this https://github.com/DavidWells/isomorphic-react-example and create another simple one,but the error message is can't find module app,is it miss  something?Or how should I change the code?thanks

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

require("node-jsx").install();
var React = require("react");
 App = React.createFactory(require("app"));


app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var markup = React.renderToString(App());  
    res.render('main', { 
     title: 'Express',
    markup: markup 
  });
});


app.listen(3000);
```

app.js

```
 var React = require("react");


var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      search: ""
    };
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-component">
        <input type="text" onChange={this.changeSearch} />
        <p><span>You are searching for: {this.state.search}</span></p>
      </div>
    );
  },
  changeSearch(event) {
    var text = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      search: text
    });
  }
});


module.exports = App;
```

main.handlebars

```
 <!DOYCYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var as = "as";
</script>

<body>
<p> main </p>
{{{markup}}}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `require("./app.js")`

Comment: You need to add the script to the html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to require a file as a module you have to give it the pathname, in this case `./app` if it is in the same directory.

So your line

```
App = React.createFactory(require("app"));
```

Should become something like

```
var App = React.createFactory(require("./app"));
```

Comment: According to my code when I type something,the state won't change.Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: If that solved it, you should make it as an accepted answer and then start another question to solve another problem.